# how to write into someone else google calendar

Tags: .net, google-calendar-api

Currently our companies calendars are managed by google account.  Is it possible to insert an entry into all the employees calendars?

I have looked into https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/

but can't find anything

Thanks

Comment: In your code, loop over all the employees' calendar IDs and insert an event for each ID.

Comment: How do I get the calendar Id's of my employees? and is there any permission and authorization issues?

Answer (score 1):

There is a domain setting that will let a service account access all accounts in the domain: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation as answered in [Cannot get access token with Google Calendar Api v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24188439/cannot-get-access-token-with-google-calendar-api-v3)

For retrieving all users in a domain you can probably use the google Admin SDK https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list

Comment: Instead of the deprecated Provisioning API, use the [Admin SDK](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list) to list the users in your domain.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new calendar and share it. 
Then make the others import this calendar.

Make sure they have it ticked/shown when browing their overview, ofcourse.

Comment: Is it possible without creating a new calendar? as what I need to write into each emolyees calendar might be different..

Comment: @user2206329 Vice versa: the employees could each share their calendar with you.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid sharing calendars, as there can be upto 1000 employees.  I was sure if you are an administrator of a domain and you manage the accounts through Google, the administrator would have access to everyone calendars?